# Passing UITableViewCell reference to other VC making it disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am doing something similar to whatsapp message info, when dragged the right chat bubble to left it shows message info in another VC.

I replicated this functionality and passing reference of cell which I am dragging to next VC.

But when I come back the cell is disappeared which reference I passed, when scrolled up and down or refreshing the table make it appear again.

Why this is happening I am only passing the reference.

Comment: well you passed the reference then on did disappear do you deallocate? I believe that as long as its a reference what ever you do with it will be replicated to the main object. unless its a copy of that object.

Comment: @Joshua No I am not deallocating and this happens when Cell will appear on next VC, If I don't display it on new VC it remain intact.

Comment: can you show some code on how you pass the reference? and how you dismiss the vc you are displaying the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying the cell (the same cell from the tableview) in a new view using addSubview:, then that view (the cell) dissapears from its previous superview. A view can only have one superview. IOW, a view can be only on one place.

Don't show the cell in the next scene (view controller). Instead build a new view (or cell) similar to the original.

BTW don't pass the cell to next VC. It is not a good practice. Try to pass data to view controllers, not views that depends on other view controllers.